# limits lhospital rule big numbers

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^{2011} + 2010^x}{-x^{2010} + 2011^x}$$

How I get it to the form to use l'hospital's rule? What's the answer?

Comment: Hint: The exponentials will eventually dominate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First notice that $a^x=\exp(x\ln a)$. Now apply the l'Hôpital's rule $2012$ times and the desired limit is

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\ln(2010))^{2012} 2010^x}{(\ln(2011))^{2012} 2011^x}$$
but the geometric sequence
$$\left(\frac{2010}{2011}\right)^x$$
converges to $0$ since  $0\le\frac{2010}{2011}<1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply l'Hopital's rule $2012$ times, you get
$$\frac{(\ln2010)^{2012}\cdot2010^x}{(\ln2011)^{2012}\cdot2011^x}=\left(\frac{\ln2010}{\ln2011}\right)^{2012}\cdot \left(\frac{2010}{2011}\right)^x\to0$$